# Node app working on localhost but not on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have a node.js app that is running fine when I do npm run dev (using nodemon) on my localhost. However when I deploy to heroku, it crashes every time.

I get an H10 error every time as well as this error:
Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'

I've tried all the usual remedies: my port is correct

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

I added a Procfile
I removed all my node_modules and put them in .gitignore

Yet I still get the crash.

I believe the line of code the error is referencing is in one of my routes, which is in the file index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User'); //Line I believe is the issue
```

I need that line in order for my app to execute properly. Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT- FOLDER STRUCTURE:

```
>config
>models
   >User.js
>node_modules
>public
>routes
   >index.js
   >users.js
>views
>app.js
>package-lock.json
>package.json
>Procfile
```

Comment: Can you show your folder structure ?

Comment: @Visrozar Just edited my post to show folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was due to case sensitivity and file nameing. Mac OS X is case insensitive (but aware) whereas Heroku is based on Linux and is case sensitive.

You can try rename `User.js` to `user.js`.

By running `heroku run bash` from your terminal, then `ls ./models/`, you can see how the `/models` folder appeared on Heroku's file system.

Comment: Did what you said and you are correct, Heroku was storing it as user.js. So I switched to user.js on my local machine and changed all instances of User to user in my files. However im still getting the same error with the capital User.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15).  I do not know if this line has any significance.

Answer (score 0):

You need **app.yaml** file in your root folder.

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
api_version: '1.0'
```